# Launch Teams chat with multiple contacts using URI scheme

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there support for initiating chat with multiple contacts using either 'im:' or 'sip:' URIs?

Similar functionality in Lync: `im:<sip:user1@host><sip:user2@host>`
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx

(Using the above format to launch Teams gives me a "We weren't able to find that contact" error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment, but we're working on extending Teams deeplinks to allow starting group chats.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MSTeams protocol mixed with [Teams Deeplinking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat). I've got it to work for my organization

`<a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com">Teams Chat</a>`